# What is $B(f, a)$ with $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: functions, notation, lebesgue-measure

What function or set of functions denotes as $B(f, a)$, where $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$? I have a feeling that this is some kind of basic notation...

Comment: Maybe the ball $\{g \in L^p \mid \|f-g\| < a\}$?

Comment: this notation comes from basic topology in case you were wondering

Comment: @Thomas Pouget, okey, thank you. Too many notations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably the ball centered at $f$ with radius $a$:
$$
B(f,a)= \left\{ g \in L^p(\mathbb{R}) \mid \|f-g\|<a \right\}.
$$